# IntelliJ WebStorm: SFTP Auth Fail

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, sftp, jetbrains-ide

Trying to SFTP local changes to a dev server using WebStorm, but getting auth fail :(. Can get SFTP working properly directly and also using plugins for other IDEs. Just upgraded to WebStorm 2017 and had it working on previous version, but that was also on a different device. My `idea.log` with debug flag on is below:

```
2017-03-28 16:26:13,296 [ 25285] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Connecting to myserver.com port 22 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,315 [ 25304] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Connection established 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,336 [ 25325] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,336 [ 25325] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,337 [ 25326] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,345 [ 25334] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - aes256-ctr is not available. 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,345 [ 25334] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - aes192-ctr is not available. 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,345 [ 25334] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - aes256-cbc is not available. 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,345 [ 25334] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - aes192-cbc is not available. 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,346 [ 25335] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,404 [ 25393] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server: 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: none 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,406 [ 25395] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: none 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,407 [ 25396] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,407 [ 25396] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client: 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,407 [ 25396] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,407 [ 25396] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,409 [ 25398] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,409 [ 25398] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,448 [ 25437] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - ssh_rsa_verify: signature true 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,449 [ 25438] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Host 'myserver.com' is known and matches the RSA host key 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,449 [ 25438] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,449 [ 25438] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,451 [ 25440] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,472 [ 25461] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,494 [ 25483] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,494 [ 25483] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Next authentication method: publickey 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,528 [ 25517] DEBUG - ins.plugins.webDeployment.sftp - Disconnecting from myserver.com port 22 
2017-03-28 16:26:13,531 [ 25520] WARN - t.connections.RemoteConnection - Retrying connecting to sftp://myserver.com:22/ in @3a81c1f4: 1 iterations 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://myserver.com/".
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:108)
at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.PatchedSftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(PatchedSftpFileProvider.java:30)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:102)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:80)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:64)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:790)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:712)
at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool.createConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:186)
at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionManager.openConnection(RemoteConnectionManager.java:115)
at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.RemoteHostTask.doRun(RemoteHostTask.java:158)
at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.RemoteHostTask.run(RemoteHostTask.java:106)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "myserver.com".
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:186)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:97)
... 23 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:182)
... 24 more
2017-03-28 16:26:13,533 [ 25522] WARN - s.webDeployment.RemoteHostTask - Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://myserver.com/". 
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://myserver.com/".
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:108)
at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.PatchedSftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(PatchedSftpFileProvider.java:30)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:102)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:80)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:64)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:790)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:712)
at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool.createConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:186)
at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionManager.openConnection(RemoteConnectionManager.java:115)
at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.RemoteHostTask.doRun(RemoteHostTask.java:158)
at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.RemoteHostTask.run(RemoteHostTask.java:106)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "myserver.com".
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:186)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:97)
... 23 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:182)
... 24 more
2017-03-28 16:28:30,883 [ 162872] ERROR - terminal.emulator.JediEmulator - Error processing OSC 1;~/axm 
2017-03-28 16:28:31,040 [ 163029] ERROR - terminal.emulator.JediEmulator - Unhandled Control sequence
parsed :ESC[?2004h
bytes read :ESC[ 
2017-03-28 16:28:31,796 [ 163785] ERROR - terminal.emulator.JediEmulator - Unhandled Control sequence
parsed :ESC[?2004l
bytes read :ESC[ 
2017-03-28 16:28:31,797 [ 163786] ERROR - terminal.emulator.JediEmulator - Error processing OSC 1;sftp 
2017-03-28 16:28:31,815 [ 163804] ERROR - terminal.emulator.JediEmulator - Error processing OSC 1;~/axm 
2017-03-28 16:28:31,933 [ 163922] ERROR - terminal.emulator.JediEmulator - Unhandled Control sequence
parsed :ESC[?2004h
bytes read :ESC[
```

Comment: Can you confirm you can connect to the server with other programs such as Filezilla and the same authenication details?

Comment: I don't mean to take the piss but for the sake of clarity can you confirm you have double and triple checked that the **Port**, **username** and **password** (or your **public key**) are valid and that your local machine has not been blocked by your server due to too many bad connections?

Comment: This might be a better fit for superuser.com

Comment: I can connect via Filezilla with no issue. And have already checked those items multiple times.

Comment: Have you recently changed any of these details (port, keys, username, etc)?. Another method may be to ask PhpStorm to clear static cache (in file menu) then close the program and restart, then re-enter the correct details from scratch. Let us know how that works out

Comment: @fNek a lot of developers use PhpStorm, this is relevant to StackOverflow

Comment: @Martin I have not changed any of those items recently. I just cleared the cache and restarted, still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you have any error logs (bad connections) on the server logs? I'm out of ideas for here though.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Thanks for your help. Hopefully I can get to the bottom of this